# Real numbers $r$ and $1/r$ whose decimal representations contain the same digits

Tags: decimal-expansion

I was wondering idly this morning about real numbers $r$ with the property that the decimal representations of $r$ and $1/r$ both contain the same nonzero digits (not necessarily the same number of times or in the same order).  Some obvious example are:

- The only nonzero digit in the decimal representation of $1/3$ is $3$.
- The only nonzero digit in the decimal representation of $10^n$ and $1/10^n$ is $1$.

Of course this property depends on the number base one uses to represent the real number.  In binary, *every* number has this property (because there is only one nonzero digit available!).  In any base $b$, the numbers $b^n$ all have this property.  Somewhat more subtly, if the base $b$ has the form $n^2+1$, then the representation of $1/n$ will be $0.nnnnnn \dots$ (which generalizes the example of $1/3$ in base $10$).

But all of these examples involve whole number $r$ and seem in some sense trivial.  Are there any nontrivial examples?  Is it possible to prove whether there exist irrational numbers with this property?

Comment: This will be also be true for almost any large number that has all the digits represented in it.

Comment: @Arthur you caught me mid-edit :-)

Comment: Trivially, the number zero does not share this property with any other number, even in base 2. Just saying 

Comment: $\pi $ (just to be ornery.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a nice class of non-trivial examples that will work in any base.  In particular, suppose that $r$ satisfies
$$
r = 1/r + n
$$
for some integer $n$.  Then $r$ and $1/r$ will have all the same digits after the exact same digits after the decimal place.  Usually, both will contain all $10$ digits somewhere in there.

For example, with $n = 1$, we have the solution 
$$
r = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}2
$$
(aka the golden ratio), and we find that
$$
r = 1.61803\dots\\
1/r = 0.61803\dots
$$

Comment: Very nice.  This can be generalized, I suppose, to finding $r$ that satisfies $r = 1/(10^k r) + n$, as that would simply pad the digits of $r$ with some zeroes after the decimal point.

Comment: (Or in base $b$, we would have $r = 1/(b^k r) + n$.)

Comment: Can you add some precision to what "usually" means?

Comment: @mweiss honestly, I'm not really sure.  It is conjectured that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational for any non-perfect square integer $n$.  If this holds, then it would follow that any irrational solution $r$ to a quadratic of the type we described would also be normal, and thus would necessarily contain every digit.

Comment: There might be a weaker condition that works here, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: "It is conjectured that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational for any non-perfect square integer $n$."  I assume you meant "normal" rather than "irrational" -- otherwise I think I can prove that conjecture for you. :)

Comment: Right... I meant normal, not irrational.